# Join two tables on date where date format is different DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I've searched on here for answer to similar problems, but I have not found a solution to the problem with DB2 SQL

I need to join two tables on dates, pulling their date information and conducting sum functions on information pulled from both tables with the eventual goal of combining both sum values together and other analysis. The date format between the tables are VARCHAR(6) that is displayed as YYYYMM and VARCHAR(32) as YYYY-MM. I do not have the ability to change the tables directly.

I've attempted the following (pesudo) solution

```
Select TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(Date.Table1) as Date1, 
       TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(Date.Table1) as Date2, 
       SUM(Value.Table1) as Sum1,
       SUM(Value.Table2) as Sum2
From Table1
Full Outer Join Table2 on Date.Table1 = Date.Table2
Order By Date.Table1, Date.Table2,
Group By Date.Table1, Date.Table2;
```

The result puts all the information on the same table, as expected, but not side by side where dates are the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of course it would be best to update these tables, as you seem to know: Anything you try is going to (at least partially) invalidate the use of indices.  That, and having a canonical form of this data would be better for other reasons, too (although changing all the relevant programs might be a pain).  Note that the best long-term solution would be to create a user-defined type, which would allow you to perform validation on the data as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the hyphen:

```
From Table1 Full Outer Join
     Table2
     on Date.Table1 = replace(Date.Table2, '-', '')
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, but I believe that I'm having a DB issue as the querry never ended lol